# How to create a Condition in batch windows?

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, command-prompt, prompt

I have a script that I am trying to create a function to execute some commands according to the system version.

To know which version of Windows I do:

```
systeminfo | Findstr / B / C: "OS Name" / C: "OS Version"> version.txt
set version = <version.txt
del version.txt
echo% version% #(variable test, ok)
```

I need the following function (more or less like I would in Linux batch):

```
if [echo% version% | Findstr / B / C: "Windows XP"> "0"] {
echo "Windows XP"
}
if [echo% version% | Findstr / B / C: "Windows 7"> "0"] {
echo "Windows 7"
}
if [echo% version% | Findstr / B / C: "Windows 8"> "0"] {
echo "Windows 8"
}
if [echo% version% | Findstr / B / C: "Windows 10"> "0"] {
echo "Windows 10"
}
```

Comment: There are literally thousands of examples of batch files all over the web of ways to identify the Windows version. _(I would also suggest that your's will be among the slowest because the systeminfo command takes some time to complete)_. That said, identifying the OS is usually only required if you are trying to control/restrict commands. Could you please provide us with your intentions once the OS is identified so that we can suggest the most suitable methods.

Comment: I have a script to install some softwares automaticaly, and somes softs can be instaled only in a determinated version of Windows.

Comment: Any decent software installer should already have the ability to determine if the system requirements are met. A 64-bit program should not be able to install on a 32-bit OS, a piece of software requiring a minimum of Windows 8 should not be able to install on Windows Vista and so on...For anything not covered all you should need to do is determine if the version is greater or equal to your minimum, not determine the product name. Incidentally the `ver` command gets the cmd.exe version not the OS version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer this method from [VER command](https://ss64.com/nt/ver.html) :

```bat
@Echo off
For /f "tokens=4,5,6 delims=[]. " %%G in ('ver') Do (set _major=%%G& set _minor=%%H& set _build=%%I) 

Echo Major version: [%_major%]
Echo Minor Version: [%_minor%]
Echo Build: [%_build%]

GOTO sub%_major%-%_minor%

:sub6-0
Echo Windows Vista or Windows 2008
goto next

:sub6-1
Echo Windows 7 or Windows 2008 R2
goto next

:sub6-2
Echo Windows 8 or Windows Server 2012
goto next

:sub6-3
Echo Windows 8.1 or Windows Server 2012
goto next

:sub10-0
:sub10-1
Echo Windows 10 or Windows 2016

:next
Echo Architecture: [%PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%]
pause
```

Or with this batch can did also the trick :

```bat
@echo off
setlocal
for /f "tokens=4-5 delims=. " %%i in ('ver') do set VERSION=%%i.%%j
if "%version%" == "5.1"     ( set "OS=Windows XP" )
if "%version%" == "5.2"     ( set "OS=Windows XP Professional x64 Edition" )
if "%version%" == "6.0"     ( set "OS=Windows Vista" )
if "%version%" == "6.1"     ( set "OS=Windows 7" )
if "%version%" == "6.2"     ( set "OS=Windows 8" )
if "%version%" == "6.3"     ( set "OS=Windows 8.1" )
if "%version%" == "10.0"    ( set "OS=Windows 10" )

echo OS is "%OS%"
echo The version is "%version%"
endlocal
pause
```

Comment: I suppose that a reasonable routine should be able to at least determine whether it is a server OS or otherwise. I say this because I thought that "5.2" was valid for Windows NET Server, Home Server and Server 2003 in both architectures? As you can imagine a routine intended to run a command not knowing the difference between a 64-bit Windows XP and a 32-bit Windows Server 2003 Datacenter Edition could be problematic.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot execute a command in a if statement, you have to use two lines:

```
ver | find /I "10.0" > nul
if not errorlevel 1 (
  echo Win10
)
ver | find /I "5.1" > nul
if not errorlevel 1 (
  echo WinXP
)
```